# virtualenvwrapper on Mac (using terminal) : Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader'

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtual-environment

Trying to finish installing virtualenvwrapper. I have already installed Python 3.8.3 and virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper but when I am exporting to setup a virtual environment location using:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS=' -p /usr/bin/python3 '
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

It says there is no directory. So I have changed my source to be

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

because after using which virtualenvwrapper.sh, that is where it is.

once I have done this though i get the error

```
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 and that PATH is
set properly.
```

What exactly do I need to change for this environment to work?